# Configuration for two domains on the same server

Tags: apache, .htaccess, httpd.conf

I have two domains pointed to the same server.
olddomain.com is configured such that DocumentRoot is /var/www/html (Apache server) and finds all HTML and PHP files here. What is the simplest way to have newdomain.com find it's files (different from olddomain.com's) from a different folder (say /var/www/html2), such that when I type:

- newdomain.com, it'll show a default index page
- newdomain.com/foobar.htm it'll show newdomain.com/foobar.htm (including seeing this in the URL bar)

?

Comment: This depends on your environment, actually. Is this a http server you operate yourself? Or a hosted platform?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create virtual hosts for each domain, very easy to do, Google it.

Comment: This is not really an answer, it should have been a comment.

Comment: This works for me as an answer. Thank you very much